# Connection refused error in Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am new in Storm.. I am stucked with below error

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
1178482 [Thread-11-SendThread(localhost:2000)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session 0x1417cd58578000b for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

Sometimes my topology works fine but when i tried again i got above error.Searched a lot in google but could nt find any clue.
I am running my topology in local cluster.. please suggest some solutions

Please find more logs below :-

```
2595 [Thread-11-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager  - State change: SUSPENDED
2596 [Thread-11-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster  - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
2596 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager  - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
3592 [Thread-11-SendThread(localhost:2000)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session 0x1417e6596c7000b for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
3895 [Thread-11-SendThread(localhost:2000)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session 0x1417e6596c7000b for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:90)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.processBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:380)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.BackgroundSyncImpl$1.processResult(BackgroundSyncImpl.java:49)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:617)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:506)
```

Please find more log :-

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
50454 [Thread-15] ERROR com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState  - Connection timed out
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72)
    at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:149)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:138)
    at com.netflix.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:85)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:134)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:125)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:34)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_.invoke(zookeeper.clj:78)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists.invoke(zookeeper.clj:117)
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__1996.set_data(cluster.clj:70)
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2415.worker_heartbeat_BANG_(cluster.clj:276)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$do_executor_heartbeats.doInvoke(worker.clj:35)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:439)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4348$exec_fn__1228__auto____4349$fn__4352.invoke(worker.clj:346)
    at backtype.storm.timer$schedule_recurring$this__1776.invoke(timer.clj:69)
    at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__1759$fn__1760.invoke(timer.clj:33)
    at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__1759.invoke(timer.clj:26)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: can you please share the code you are using to run the topology. What do you mean by `when I tried again` ? Are you getting this error randomly ?

Comment: TopologyBuilder tBuilder=new TopologyBuilder();
  tBuilder.setSpout("oracle-reader", new OracleDBSourceSpout());
  tBuilder.setBolt("writer", new WriteToFileBolt()).shuffleGrouping("oracle-reader");
  
  
  Config conf=new Config();
  conf.setDebug(false);
  conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
  LocalCluster cluster= new LocalCluster();
  cluster.submitTopology("Getting-Started-Topologie",conf,tBuilder.createTopology());                                above is my topology code .... ya i m getting this error randomly...

Comment: Which storm version you are using , looks like a case of improper zookeeper shut down, are you facing this error after getting an exception while running your topology? Also can you post some more error logs

Comment: i am using 0.8.2 version.i am getting this error while running my topology. no exception before that.

Comment: what I meant was if this is happening once you get an exception running your topology (and then try to run it again) as u mentioned that its random and not consistent .. you can take look [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/issues/259) with the similar issue and it seems that the reason because of improper shutdown of zookeeper. Can you post some more logs if possible

Comment: I have added more logs in my post please check..ya as per my analysis i am getting this error because that port is not free and is randomly means once it will run perfectly, immedietly if u run again it will show this error after some time again it will work perfectly.I cant configure port because i m running in local mode so all config for connections is as per jars.So i am not getting any clue to resolve this error.

Comment: What I found is this is a wired issue faced by few people and I couldn't find a proper fix for this .. in some places people get rid of it after upgrading to a higher version (but in 0.8.2 it should be fine) .. Can you try to run the [ExclamationTopology](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.java) from the storm-starter project in github and see how it goes .. I can provide my pom.xml with 0.8.2 if you like .. it seems working fine at my end

Comment: i tried answer you accepted but didn't work with me by tried  2000 and 20000 but didn't work . is there another solution for this problem or should i  change the number of time for Thread.sleep ?

Comment: Are you getting this error randomly or frequently.. if its random them main cause is that port is not free.. u can try to free that port or either by increasing wait time.. so that zookeeper shutdown properly..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just encountered with this problem, too. My problem is the running time is set too short.The zookeeper do not have enough time to shut down properly.Look at the code below:

```
    builder.createTopology());

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cluster.shutdown();
}
```

You should set enough time before the cluster.shutdown() was called. At first, I set Thread.sleep(1000), then the same problem occurred as yours. After I changed the time, this problem never showed up again.