# Difference between shutdown and kill topology method and how to kill the topology

Tags: java, apache-storm

we are running word count topology in local mode.When we use shut down method we are getting the errors like "java.net.connectException" and entire process goes shutdown.when we use cluster.killtopology method the process cannot be terminated fully.While using both killtopology method and shutdown method sometimes topology is executed sometimes shows the error "java.net.connectException" and entire process gets shutdown.
    Can you please tell what will be the issue?

This is our code:

**Main programm:**

```
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;

public class TopologyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //Topology definition
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("word-reader",new WordReader());
        builder.setBolt("word-normalizer", new WordNormalizer()).shuffleGrouping("word-reader");
        builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounter(),2).fieldsGrouping("word-normalizer", new Fields("word"));
        //Configuration
        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.put("wordsFile","E:\\words.txt");

        conf.setDebug(false);
        //Topology run
        conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("wordcount", conf, builder.createTopology());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**Spout program:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;
import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;

public  class  WordReader implements IRichSpout {
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
    Map<String, Object> count;

    private FileReader fileReader;
    private boolean completed = false;
    private TopologyContext context;

    public boolean isDistributed() {return false;}
    public void ack(Object msgId) {
        System.out.println("OK:"+msgId);
    }
    public void close() {}
    public void fail(Object msgId) {
        System.out.println("FAIL:"+msgId);
    }

    /**
     * The only thing that the methods will do It is emit each
     * file line
     */
    public void nextTuple() {
        /**
         * The nextuple it is called forever, so if we have been readed the file
         * we will wait and then return
         */
         if(completed){
             try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 //Do nothing
             }
             return;
         }
         String str;
         //Open the reader
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
         try{
             //Read all lines
             while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
                 /**
                   * By each line emmit a new value with the line as a their
                   */
                 this.collector.emit(new Values(str),str);
             }
         }catch(Exception e){
             throw new RuntimeException("Error reading tuple",e);
         }finally{
             completed = true;
         }
     }

    /**
     * We will create the file and get the collector object
     */
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        try {
            this.context = context;
            this.fileReader = new FileReader(conf.get("wordsFile").toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file["+conf.get("wordFile")+"]");
        }
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    /**
     * Declare the output field "word"
    */
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("str"));
    }

    public void deactivate(){}
    public void activate(){}
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration(){return count;}
}
```

**Bolt normalizer program:::**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;

public class WordNormalizer implements IRichBolt {
    private OutputCollector collector;
    Map<String, Object> count;

    public void cleanup() {}
    /**
    * The bolt will receive the line from the
    * words file and process it to Normalize this line
    *
    * The normalize will be put the words in lower case
    * and split the line to get all words in this
    */
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        String sentence = input.getString(0);
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        for(String word : words){
            word = word.trim();
            if(!word.isEmpty()){
                word = word.toLowerCase();
                //Emit the word
                List a = new ArrayList();
                a.add(input);
                collector.emit(a,new Values(word));
            }
        }
        // Acknowledge the tuple
        collector.ack(input);
    }

    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    /**
    * The bolt will only emit the field "word"
    */
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration(){return count;}
    }
```

Bolt counter program::

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;

public class  WordCounter implements IRichBolt {
    Integer id;
    String name;
     Map<String, Integer> counters;
    Map<String, Object> count;
    private OutputCollector collector;

    /**
    * At the end of the spout (when the cluster is shutdown
    * We will show the word counters
    */
    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        System.out.println("-- Word Counter ["+name+"-"+id+"] --");
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counters.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+": "+entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    /**
     * On each word We will count
     */
    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        String str = input.getString(0);
        /**
         * If the word dosn't exist in the map we will create
* this, if not We will add 1
         */
        if(!counters.containsKey(str)){
            counters.put(str, 1);
        }else{
            Integer c = counters.get(str) + 1;
            counters.put(str, c);
        }
        //Set the tuple as Acknowledge
        collector.ack(input);
    }

    /**
     * On create
     */
    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.counters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        this.collector = collector;
        this.name = context.getThisComponentId();
        this.id = context.getThisTaskId();
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("str", "c"));
    }

    public void deactivate(){}

    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration(){return count;}

}
```

Please guide us to solve the problem.

Comment: topology is sometimes running sometimes shows error please help us

Answer (score 1):

With the `cluster.killTopology("WordCount");` method you kill only topology, cluster will continue in it's work. With the `cluster.shutdown();` you kill whole cluster with running topologies in that cluster.

I don't think that killing topology is reason of your problem. It would by fine to attach log from application. Try to check this [treat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151897/connection-refused-error-in-storm). Probably ports which is storm using are randomly in use and that cause your problem.